# Most efficient way of searching for a string in a list of strings?

Tags: sql-server, string, c#-4.0

I'm developing a custom email client in C#. One of the obvious requirements is that I don't download already downloaded messages. This is done by comparing a unique ID string against messages stored in my database.

The database stores emails for multiple users and multiple accounts so the unique ID will not necessarily be unique in my database.

Currently I have something like this:

```
List<String> DownloadedUIDs = BLL.EmailsDataSource.ViewEmailUIDs(AccountNo);     
foreach (string uid in serveruids) {
   if (DownloadedUIDs.Contains(uid)) continue; // don't download messages we already have  
   ...
}
```

I know the Contains() method performs a linear search which is very inefficient. If there are 5000 emails stored on the server then 5000 linear searches need to be made on a list of 5000 emails to determine whether or not the email already exists.

Would I see better performance asking SQL Server to order the unique IDs and then perform a Binary Search on them, or storing the unique IDs in a Hash Table? Or using some other data structure?

Does anyone know of any similar performance comparisons that have been made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do some performance testing and these are the results I got (from connecting to the mail server to verifying all 3000 emails had been downloaded):

1. Unsorted List = 418ms
2. Sorted List = 329ms
3. Sorted Set = 312ms
4. Sort List + Binary Search = 310ms
5. **HashSet = 305ms**

So it seems given my data at least that HashSets are quickest at doing this though there is little to choose between all 4 optimised methods.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is one of the two following:

1. Perform the search in the database with the help of an index that contains all columns that together make a unique id. Searching is then a simple select.
2. Use a Hashmap.

Comment: I don't understand your first suggestion - I can't perform the search in the database since (in my example at least) I would have to perform the search 5000 times resulting in 5000 SQL calls.

Comment: @cusimar9: What prevents you from doing the select in a Stored Procedure and pass all 5000 IDs to that stored procedure? Then all selects would run in the database and you would have only one call to the database.

Comment: I could do that if it were the quickest way but I don't think it would be

Answer (score 0):

You could store the messages in a Binary Tree structure that is indexed by its uid. This way, if you end up trying to add with a message that already exists, you'll hit the case `current_node.uid == new_node.uid` and it can be discarded as a duplicate.

This way, you system undergoes fewer changes, and you get to enjoy the performance of b-trees! =D

Comment: Presumably the performance of this would be identical to using a Hashtable?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your hash function, it could be varying degrees of faster, yes. But Hashing can lead to collisions, which could generate false positives when checking for used uids, leaving some new messages unchecked. For this case, I'd stick with reliable, your clients will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that the following response doesn't explicitly answer your question(s). However, I believe it does respond to the heart of your question which is concerned with disallowing duplicate records in the db table while maintaining quality system performance.

Instead of checking for duplicate emails prior to inserting an email, consider/test the following logic:

1. Specify a Unique Key constraint on
   your email db table
2. try/catch your INSERT statement for
   a unique violation

This method not only **guarantees** avoidance of duplicate emails, but also avoids the linear search concern that you mentioned.

Although, this method may incur a slight performance hit compared to a SELECT check, it only will do so if a violation is caught. So, if you think the chance of duplicate emails is very low (a true exception), then you may find that this method is most efficient (and foolproof) compared to a SELECT check.

To back up my point, somewhat, check out "Lesson #4" of Paul Nielsen's list of "[10 Lessons from 35k tps](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/12/12/10-lessons-from-35k-tps.aspx)"

Comment: Unfortunately this is entirely the wrong approach for this application. Like I said there may be 5001 emails on the server and I have 5000 emails on my system... one of those emails is new and the others already exist. Selects / Inserts for every record would suffer a huge performance hit.